# Auto capitalization of first letter of edit text not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to add `EditText` with `inputtype = textCapWords` but it is not working for me .
I have also tried `textcapsentences` but it is also not working.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d1"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field_account"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/Last_Name"
    android:inputType="se"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:textColor="@color/black000"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_hint"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_n" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you have set it correctly because in the code posted above you have `android:inputType="se"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**
     remove   `android:inputType`

```
// add this it Capitalize The First Letter Of Every Word.

 android:capitalize="words"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type of your Edittext.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/d1"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
    android:background="@drawable/text_field_account"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/Last_Name"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:maxWidth="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:textColor="@color/black000"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text_color_hint"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_n" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you

```
yourEdittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```